# How to trigger an event if a group of elements have not been clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

What way would you be able to trigger an on blur style event, only if a group of elements are not clicked.
for example: if you wanted to make a custom drop down after an input, here is a fiddle of what I'm trying to achieve; http://jsfiddle.net/hruahrpc/
Clicking on any element that is not in the first list, should cause the list to collapse.

I have tried stopping the blur, however I can't seem to get it to work.

```js
$('ul').hide();
$('input').focus(
    function(){    
        $('ul').show()
    }
);
$('.hidelist').click(
    function(){
        $('ul').hide();
    }

)
$('input').blur(
    function(){
        $('ul').hide();
    }
);
```

```css
.results{
    background-color:pink;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" />
<div class="results">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">I have other functionality and I don't hide the list</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">I have other functionality and I don't hide the list</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">I have other functionality and I don't hide the list</a></li>
    </ul>
    <ul class="hidelist">    
        <li><a href="#"  >I make the list disapear</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>


<div>I am any other element and I make the list disapear</div>
```

Clicking on any element that is not in the first list, should cause the list to collapse.

Comment: This question is unclear. Please provide a clear statement of what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: I'm trying have the on blur function trigger the list to hide, unless a button is pressed that stops the event.

Comment: @user3784864 I posted an answer for u that works check it out and let me know if that is what you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this.  It is a little complicated but because of the ordering of the events it was hard to come up with a way to do what you want but this works [working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/f6u74bef/1/):

Javascript Code:

```
var stopHide = false;
var okToExecute = false;
var blurTest = false;
var timeout = undefined;
$('ul').hide()
$('#input1').focus(
    function(){
        $('ul').show();
    }
);
$('.hidelist').click(
    function () {
        stopHide = false;
        okToExecute = true;
        $('#input1').blur();
    }
);
$('.dontHide').click(
    function() {
        stopHide = true;
        okToExecute = true;
        $('#input1').blur();
    }
);
$('input').blur(
    function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        if(okToExecute)
        {
            if(!stopHide)
            {
                $('ul').hide();
            }
            else
            {
                $('#input1').focus();
            }
            okToExecute = false;
            blurTest = true;
        }
        if(timeout == undefined)
        {
            timeout = true;
            setTimeout(function(){console.log(blurTest);if(!blurTest){                      $('ul').hide();}blurTest = false;timeout = undefined;}, 200);
        }
    }
);
```

HTML:

```
<input id="input1" type="text" />
<div class="results">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#" class="dontHide">I have other functionality and I don't hide the list</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" class="dontHide">I have other functionality and I don't hide the list</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" class="dontHide">I have other functionality and I don't hide the list</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" class="hidelist" >I make the list disapear</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
</br>
<div>I am any other element and I make the list disapear</div>
```

Comment: @user3784864 check it out

Comment: I managed to get the same effect using stopPropagation and changing the html slightly. http://jsfiddle.net/hruahrpc/2/
However I think This is the better solution as it doesn't require a change to the html

Comment: As I think YOU had the better solution :) Thanks for helping my learning

Comment: @user3784864 your welcome I'm glad I was able to help!

Answer (score 1):

Thats the way I do it. Hope I've been helpful.

Regards.

```js
$('ul').hide()
$('input').focus(
    function(){    
        $('ul').show()
    }
);

$('input').blur(
    function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        $('.hidelist').click(function(){
            $('ul').hide();
        });
        // You can handle other thing here
    }
);
```

```css
.results{
    background-color:pink;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" />
<div class="results">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">I have other functionality and I don't hide the list</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">I have other functionality and I don't hide the list</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">I have other functionality and I don't hide the list</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" class="hidelist" >I make the list disapear</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
</br>
<div>I am any other element and I make the list disapear</div>
```

OR use this :

```
  $('ul').hide()
    $('input').focus(
        function(){    
            $('ul').show()
        }
    );

    $('.hidelist').click(function(){
         $('ul').hide();
    });
```

Comment: I'm trying have the on blur function trigger the list to hide, unless a button is pressed that stops the event.

Comment: I dont understand what you want. Can you explain a bit more please

Comment: I want to keep the functionality that you implemented but also trigger the list to be hidden if anything but the list is clicked.

Comment: like $(!'ul').click(){
  $('ul').hide();
}